# UITextField becomeFirstResponder but the keyboard doesn't showed

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I create a uitextfield and explicitly I call:

```
[myTextField setEnabled:YES];
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

but the keyboard isn't showed. Can I explicitly call the keyboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is possible if the user has an external keyboard enabled. You CANNOT explicitly call the keyboard

Answer (score 1):

have you checked if your textfield is properly initialized ?  Or is it for some reason nil.
or you did not connect it properly in IB ?
Maybe you can provide more information ?